# Cart Rules - Not logged in

Tags: magento2, cart, rules

I've set up a cart rule that applies if:
payment method is Bank Transfer.

It is always applied, except when an order is placed as a guest. Can you help me?

NB: All the user groups present are selected

Answer (score 0):

Remember to let the **Uses per Customer** empty

> Uses per Customer
>
> Determines how many times the coupon code can be used by the same
>   registered customer who belongs to any selected customer group. Does
>   **not apply** to guest shoppers who are members of the **NOT LOGGED IN**
>   customer group, or to customers who shop without logging in to their
>   accounts. For no limit, leave blank.

Comment: Uses per Customer is set to 0. The rule works correctly if the user is logged in. Can it depend on the checkout page?